# Is it possible to compile the program without .c file in make file?

Tags: makefile

I have a make file like this

```
tar: ex.o
     cc -o out ex.o
```

It is compiling the file ex.c,how is this done without specifying the ex.c in this make file.

Answer (score 3):

Make has build in some Implicit Rules, which make this work.

See the Manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html

Comment: You mean built-in rules. Not every implicit rule is built in - you can add your own implicit rules.